# In Mean JS how can we run 2 application in 2 different port?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

My application is developed in mean.js, this has Management and Portal. At present management in run in port 3000 and portal in 4000. But now I would like to run management in 3000 and portal in 3001. As by default the test (Jasmine & mocha) is running in 5858 port I am not able to run my app,its showing an error

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1250:14)
    at listen (net.js:1286:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide details about your app or what OS it is running on. So it is difficult to be specific.

You should be able to set a different default port when launching the application.

E.g. 
On linux

$`PORT=8080 node app.js`

On Windows

`c:> set PORT=8080
c:> node app.js`